# Converting Matlab's Uint8 to C++'s Integer

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, vector

I have to pass data of variable length from Matlab/Simulink to a C++ S Function.

In Matlab, when I apply the `uint8` function to a string, I get a vector (or array in C++) in return. But, depending on the length of my string, the resulting vector will have variable lengths. So, if my input is `abc`, the uint8 function returns a vector of length 1x3, and if it is `abcde`, I get a vector of 1x5.

So far so good. Now, if I want to send this resulting array to C++, is there a way of doing it so that it accounts for the variable length of the resulting vector? I read that VLAs are not allowed in C++, but is there a solution to this?

Comment: `std::vector`?  `new uint8_t [n]`?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/ug/s-functions-using-variable-size-signals.html